# nginx proxy to tomcat

Tags: nginx, tomcat, reverse-proxy

**I've realized it belongs more to serverfault so I moved it there: [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/1051660/nginx-proxy-to-tomcat-with-ssl)**

I went through dozens of tutorials and I can't figure out following:

I have my compiled vue application in /var/www/mydomain.com and I want it to be shared as static content.

My backend running on 8080 by tomcat with public APIs on /api/something... URLs. The URLs are hardcoded including the "api" part.

I'd like to configure nginx to proxy mydomain.com/api/something... requests to tomcat and rest be served statically from /var/www/mydomain.com. Everything served through SSL.

I litterally don't need anything else.

Can you help me configure the nginx and tomcat to achieve that? Thank you!

**nginx config /etc/nginx/sites-available/mydomain.com**

```
upstream tomcat {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        #listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

        root /var/www/mydomain.com;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

       server_name _ mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /api/ {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://tomcat;
        }

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = www.mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


       listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

       server_name _ mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
   return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

**Tomcat config server.xml**

```
        <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               address="127.0.0.1"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Current situation is that when I go to mydomain.com/api/docs where swagger should be running, I get redirected back to mydomain.com or get 500 or 502 error.

Comment: Remove the ending slash from the `proxy_pass` command: it should be `proxy_pass http://tomcat`. Without the `/` it does not change the URI path, with a `/` it will remove the `/api` prefix before forwarding the request to Tomcat.

Comment: Thank you. I removed it, but when going to mydomain.com/api/docs, it still redirects me to mydomain.com

Comment: You can check both the nginx and Tomcat access log to see which one is sending the redirect.

Comment: I don't see it in neither place. When I go to mydomain.com, it's in /var/log/nginx/ log. When I go to .../api/docs, it not there neither in /var/log/tomcat9/localhost_access_log.2021-01-29.txt

Comment: Remove the `listen 127.0.0.1;` directive, which tells the first `server` to listen on `127.0.0.1:80`.

Comment: Removed but nothing changed. Tomcat access log still empty, nginx log contains just / record. I've updated the "nginx config /etc/nginx/sites-available/mydomain.com" so it matches current state.